# Embedding GDB breakpoints

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am writing an application that recovers from an error by throwing an exception.

However when debugging I would like my debugger to stop at the point of my error before the exception is thrown. Is there anyway to add some code that will cause GDB to interrupt the execution with some piece of code.

I am interested in both ARM and x86 architectures some something cross platform will be useful.

Edit: I am looking for some breakpoint instruction or a macros that wraps one.

Comment: You're asking "is there any way GDB can predict that I'm about to throw an exception, and yank on the breaks before the CPU can execute another instruction". I think you know the answer though ;)

Comment: Are you after adding something that "if I get here, break" every time that particular code is reached?

Comment: @Mats, that is what I am asking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a "breakpoint instruction" to your code. Most OS's that I know of ignores breakpoints if no debugger is attached.

It is compiler and processor dependent what instruction you use for this, but in most compilers there is an "intrinsic" or "builtin" function, such as `DebugBreak();` for MS compilers and `__builtin_trap();` for gcc and related.

Edit: `__builtin_trap();` is a bad idea, as it will stop the code from running further at all. Instead, using inline assembler:

```
inline void DebugBreak()
{
#if defined(X86)
    __asm__ __volatile__("int 3");
#elif defined(ARM)
    __asm__ __volatile__("bkpt"); 
#else
  #error DebugBreak not defined for this architecture or no architecture defined.
#endif
}
```

should work for x86 & arm - you may want to have "better" names for the architecture choice macros - I don't do much work with varying architectures, so I haven't memorised exactly what the official names are.

Comment: This is more or less what I am looking for. The only problem is that __builtin_trap tends to kill execution.

Comment: Sorry, went by another answer, which appears to be "poor" for these purposes. Edit about to happen...

Comment: Using clang, I got the error "error: invalid operand for instruction" on the "int 3".

Changing it to be "int3" fixed this.

Comment: How to do the same on x86-64?

Answer (score 2):

Setting this:

```
catch throw
```

should give you what you are after.

See [this section](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html#Set-Catchpoints) of the [user manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).